# Asynchronous Socket Programming

Tags: c#-2.0

I've created a project using socket programming.  If I connect a single client to my server, the data I send from my client is successfully received by the server.  But whenever I connect more than one client, only one client's data is received by the server. The other clients fail to connect.  How can I make the server accept all new incoming connections, and how can I make the server receive two files from the same client?

Comment: @karthik:  Please continue working on your grammatical skills.  :)  It was very difficult to figure out what your question was.

Comment: Sounds like your project needs some re doing. Put some code here so that we dont have to guess what you did

Comment: ok let me correct my gramatical mistakes,please give me some sugessions for the above questions

Comment: I didn't see the original question, but the re-worded question makes sense to me, and it looks like a good question, so I'm giving this a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code uses BeginAccept, EndAccept methods to accept new connection asynchonously, don't forget to call again BeginAccept after EndAccept call in your AcceptCallback.

Regards